# how to decide the active slide in angular-ui-bootstrap carousel

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) is the official example in the documentation about the angular-ui-bootsratp carousel.

But I could not replicate it in my own case, as the slide.active is not working.

```
<uib-carousel  interval="1000" no-wrap="false">
    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active= "slide.active">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center"><h3>{{ slide.Title }}</h3></div>
        <img ng-src="{{slide.Image }}" style="margin:auto;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="col-xs-7">
                <p>{{ slide.Content }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```

Also where do they set up the slide.active value at the first place in the documentation? I did not see they set it up in the controller. Do I need to set it up? Am I missing anything?

Comment: Problem solved!  I double checked my angular.min.js and angular-animate.js' version. I was using 1.4.7 and 1.4.9. I changed angular.min.js to version 1.4.9. Then it worked!